# Cannot access an HPE OfficeConnect Switch 1820 24G J9980A via telnet when using PuTTy

Tags: windows-7, putty, switch, telnet

I am trying to access the switch through telnet using PuTTY and it says

```
PuTTY Fatal Error network error: Connection refused.
```

I researched online to see how to enable `telnet` on the switch, but I couldn't find any option for that. Telnet on my Windows 7 64-bit system has been enabled.

Can anyone help me on how to enable telnet on the HPE OfficeConnect Switch 1820 24G J9980A?

Comment: Have you tried SSH instead? What are the officially-support means of remote management for that switch? Also, is remote management enabled for that/those port(s)?

Comment: I tried SSH as well, doesn't let me in. error shows: Network Error: Connection Refused. The connection is One-to-one with the switch. there is no option to enable telnet through the web interface. Do you think the HP1820 switch doesnt support telnet?

Answer (score 1):

The HPE 18xx series don't support telnet or SSH, just HTTP/HTTPS. Their lowest, fully managed series is the 2530; 2xxx have complete management. Some 19xx have a minimal console interface.

Comment: Thank you, does anyone know if i can work with ipv6 on the 18xx series?

Comment: You can work with IPv6 on any switches in that they don't care whether they transport IPv4, IPv6 or anything else. Management on 18xx seems to be IPv4 only though. The lowest series with v6 (web) management and routing seems to be OfficeConnect 1910.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a command line interface to the switch by using [this set of Python-based scripts](https://github.com/BookGin/hp1820-cli).

They seem to have some author-specific functionality embedded in them, so handle with care and be prepared to tinker with them.